# Trouble printing file

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble printing this list of cities here's the code I'm using

Update: I inserted

```
print(repr(folderpath))
```

Here's the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/week_2_Lab.py", line 72, in <module>
citylist = os.listdir(folderpath + "\NA_Cities.dbf")
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Michaelf\\Desktop\\Test_Folder\\LabData\\NA_Cities.dbf/*.*'
```

> > > 

```
citylist = os.listdir(folderpath + "\NA_Cities.dbf")
print citylist
```

Here is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/week_2_Lab.py", line 71, in <module>
citylist = os.listdir(folderpath + "\NA_Cities.dbf")
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Michaelf\\Desktop\\Test_Folder\\LabData\\NA_Cities.dbf/*.*'
```

Comment: I think is it the \\ but I didn't write those in the code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to programming and python

Comment: What is `folderpath`?  Would you mind putting `print(repr(folderpath))` into your code *before* the error line?

Comment: folderpath = "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\Test_Folder\LabData"

Comment: Sure I'll put that in right now

Comment: Don't apologize that's why we're here :)

Comment: Have you tried putting `r` before each string?  That is, `folderpath = r"C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\Test_Folder\LabData"`  That makes it a raw string so that the backslashes will be taken literally.

Comment: Thank you,  I am trying to access a NA_Cities.dbf in LabData and print selected features of the list

Comment: On the side, it doesn't look like you put the `print()` call in the right place since the traceback is for a different line.  You should put that call before the `citylist = ...` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NA_Cities.dbf` looks like a file name instead of a directory. `os.listdir` will return all the files in a directory. Try using `open(os.path.join(folderpath, 'NA_Cities.dbf'))` instead, see [open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: citylist = open(os.path.join(folderpath + 'NA_Cities.dbf'))
print citylist

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michaelf/Desktop/GEOG M173/week_2_Lab.py", line 72, in <module>
    citylist = open(os.path.join(folderpath + 'NA_Cities.dbf'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Michaelf\\Desktop\\Test_Folder\\LabDataNA_Cities.dbf'